# Kafka Admin Client giving Timeout Error for ListTopic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, azkaban

Hi I am trying to run this code in
but it is working fine in another EC2 Azkaban instance but not giving below error for another instance.

```
private val adminprops = new Properties() 
adminprops.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"Kafka Endpoint")
private val admin = AdminClient.create(adminprops)

def topicExist(topicName: String): Boolean = {
 val result = admin.listTopics.names.get.contains(topicName)
 result
}
```

"Kafka Exception java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node
assignment. Call: listTopics"

Answer (score 2):

Network problem or setting problem.

1. make sure "bootstrap.servers" is correct，right host and port.
2. make sure the network is ok between the client and the broker server.

The default timeout of adminClient is 120000ms(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG). Normally,list topics return immediately.

Comment: Some time the network this error is coming and sometime not. So is there any solution on it

Comment: Kafka's bottleneck often occurs in disk capacity and bandwidth. I suggest you first check to see if bandwidth usage is consistently high, and if so, check if the producer has message compression turned on, which will significantly reduce bandwidth usage.

Comment: Regardless of the cause of the network problem, look at the scenario you are using, there are some examples of solutions:
Method 1: The request timeout can be reduced here, for example, to 2s, and catch the timeout exception to identify the network problem, try again after a while.
Method 2: Get the topic list periodically to allow short-term data inconsistency. When you get the topic, use the cache
Method 3: Query the zookeeper of kafka directly by yourself, if there is no way. Kafka keep its meta data in zookeeper.
It is recommended that you locate and resolve network problems first.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using java8, that may also give these timeout errors for unknown reasons. I switched to Java17/21 and the timeout issues went away. Hope it helps some.